# Creating a log file for each and every test case with executed test case name

Tags: automated-testing, selenium

I am working on selenium automation for one of the project, I have a number of test cases I want to create a separate log file for each and every test case

**Example :** Suppose I have two test cases with names X and Y, when I execute all the test cases (X and Y), then I need to create folder (in parallel to execution) with current time stamp and inside that folder I need to create two log files with name same as the test case names (i.e. X and Y)

please help if any body having idea

Note : I am using Log4j framework with java language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `appenders` to achieve this. Try the process below :

1. Write a logic to create directory at runtime with timestamp.
   Use DateFormat and Date to get timestamp as you need.

   `File dir = new File(DateFormatObj.format(DateObj));
    dir.mkdir();
    System.setProperty("tempFolder",dir.getAbsolutePath());`
2. Write logic for appender in each test case (or log4j.xml i didnt try that out).

   `FileAppender fileApp = new FileAppender();`

// Assuming your class name is your test name

```
 `fileApp.setFile(System.getProperty("tempFolder") + "\\" + "this.getClass().getSimpleName()" + ".log");`
```

3. Call folder creation method as your Test Case/Suite starts. Logs will be generated specific to your test case and all will move to folder created.

Answer (score -1):

can we use this appender.....

**testname**
         **testrun**
      
      
         
            ${testname}.log
            
               **${testname}.%i.log**
               1
               100
            
            
               10MB
            
            
               %d{ISO8601} %-5level %C{1} [%M:%L] [%thread] - %msg%n

Comment: can you give information on why this is a better solution, what it offers over other options?  Maybe break down what each part means and how it is used in this context

Comment: Hi Sunil, is this an answer/suggestion? Or is this a new question?